# Alternative to NSoup for Windows Store Applications

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, jsoup, windows-store-apps

Is there an alternative to NSoup for Windows Store Apps?

I'm unable to publish my app because it fails the certifications for the following reason:

Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:

```
API System.ICloneable in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.IO.FileStream in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.UriFormatException in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Web.HttpUtility in SYSTEM.WEB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B03F5F7F11D50A3A is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.String.Format(System.String,System.Object) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.String.Format(System.String,System.Object,System.Object) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeFile in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeFtp in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeGopher in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeHttp in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeHttps in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeMailto in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeNetPipe in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeNews in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Uri.UriSchemeNntp in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.UriFormatException.#ctor(System.String) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.IO.FileStream.get_Name in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(System.String,System.Object) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.String.Compare(System.String,System.String,System.Boolean) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.WebRequest.GetRequestStream in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.WebRequest.GetResponse in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Text.Encoding.GetString(System.Byte[]) in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_AllowAutoRedirect(System.Boolean) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.WebRequest.set_Timeout(System.Int32) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_ReadWriteTimeout(System.Int32) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader,System.String) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Referer(System.String) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_UserAgent(System.String) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.Add(System.String,System.String) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.get_Keys in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.KeysCollection.GetEnumerator in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.get_Item(System.String) in SYSTEM, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(System.String,System.Text.Encoding) in SYSTEM.WEB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B03F5F7F11D50A3A is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls this API.
API System.IO.Stream.Close in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. NSoup.dll calls t
```

his API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

It's a lovely HTML parser that is commonly recommended for this. It will take malformed HTML and massage it into XHTML and then a traversable DOM, like the XML classes. So, is very useful for the code you find in the wild.